# TXT file exists on server, but it can't be found

Tags: flash, text-files

I'm working on a simple music player page, but encountered a problem after uploading it to a public server.

I have a flash MP3 player that loads its playlist from a TXT file. The code where I run it looks like this:

```
<object data="player_mp3_multi.swf" height="400" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="620">
    <param name="movie" value="player_mp3_multi.swf" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="playlist=some_playlist.txt&amp;shuffle=1&amp;bgcolor1=000000&amp;bgcolor2=000000&amp;buttoncolor=ff0000&amp;buttonovercolor=ffffff&amp;slidercolor1=ff0000&amp;slidercolor2=990000&amp;sliderovercolor=ffffff&amp;textcolor=a4a4a4&amp;playlistcolor=222327&amp;currentmp3color=ffffff&amp;scrollbarcolor=ff0000&amp;scrollbarovercolor=ffffff&amp;showvolume=1&amp;volume=100&amp;volumewidth=80&amp;playlistalpha=100&amp;showloading=always&amp;loadingcolor=a4a4a4&amp;showplaylistnumbers=0&amp;width=620&amp;height=400&amp;loadingcolor=ff0000&amp;showinfo=1" />
</object>
```

Everything works fine on local server, the playlist loads up and the player plays its songs. But as I uploaded the page to an online server, everything works except the playlist that is not loaded up. It also doesn't load up if I use the full URL of the TXT file, but if I upload the playlist file to an outside server and put in its URL, it works without any problem.

The page inspector says that the server can't find the TXT file even if it is there just in the same folder as the index file where I try to use it. I have many different playlist files to try, but none of them can be loaded up. All the playlist files has the 644 perission just like all the other files on the server directory. I have tried to change it to 744 and 755 but it didn't helped.

I tried to reach the playlists files through the browser by URL, but nothing happened, only a blank page appeared. If I tried to Save link as.. on any of them from the index list, dowload couldn't be done because it said that the file isn't found. But if I try to reach the file through an FTP URL, it displays correctly in the browser.

So the playlist files are there but somehow the online server can't open them. I have no idea what more can I do...

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code doesn't look like it's pointing to a TXT file.. Perhaps the player_mp3_multi.swf is referencing an absolute path that exists on the LOCAL environment, but not on the SERVER? Maybe you need a "playlist=someplaylist.txt" in the FlashVars?

Comment: shouldn't it be
`playlist=http://www.domain.com/some_playlist.txt`
?

Comment: sry  meant `http%3A//www.doamain.com/path/to/list/playlist.txt`

Comment: @Rob W The SWF file is on the server, it loads up perfectly but with empty playlist.

Comment: @AvnerSolomon I forgot to tell that I also tried it, but without any success...

Comment: @PrincessOfSecret Using firebug, or some sort of HTTP monitor, watch the NET tab and see if any requests to the playlist.txt are made. If not, then the SWF is not making any requests to it.

Comment: Also, check your htaccess, perhaps it could also have a `.txt` entry that `deny from all`'s or similar..

Comment: can we have the path to the txt?
also might want to check if server doesn't serve txt file. Migh want to change to some random extension. rename playlist.txt to playlist.html both the file itself and into the flashvars

Comment: @RobW htaccess contains only "RewriteBase /", nothing more.

Comment: @RobW As I monitored the request, the request for the playlist file was sent, but it failed because file couldn't be found.

Comment: Check your httpd.conf or vhosts config file, perhaps there's blocking there. Check your apache logs as well, if possible.

Comment: By the way, the flash player actually displays anything on its list that is written between "playlist=" and "&", and if it's a TXT or XML file, it opens it and displays its contents. As I put anything other there than my files, it is in the list area. It's strange because locally everything works without any problem... It drives me crazy...

Comment: I was digging a bit in the forum of the server where I uploaded my site, and I found something that they don't allow opening TXT files for security reasons... Well, in this case it seems I have to upload them to somewhere else and use that outside URLs...

But anyway, thanks for your will to help!